# Is there any way to access a local SQL Server database in Angular?

Tags: sql-server, angular, database, local

I know that there are several ways to access, by having a Web API. But I need a way for a local SQL Server database

Comment: Accessing a local and remote database is no different; just use the relevant connection string.

Comment: You can't connect database directly from anguar. Angular is just client side framework . Use backend . Create API and call API using HttpClient from Angular

Comment: @Larnu how can i use a connection string?

Comment: My point is that the method you use is no different. If the instance is remote, or local, the technology doesn't change.

Comment: Angular is javascript. Javascript runs in a browser, and doesn't have access to anything except the document model in the page it's running in. All it can do is call web API's. You'll always need a web API to be the middle man

Comment: What do you mean with a 'local SQL Server' ? you mean local to the user so on the machine Angular is running on?